# FilterAttributes conflicting Compress, RegexFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, compression, action-filter

I have a controller action like so

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Put)]
[InsertScript(Order = 1)]
[Compress(Order = 2)]
public ViewResult Service(Page page) { //omitted }
```

The InsertScript attribute applied a Response.Filter

```
response.Filter = new RegexResponseFilter(response.Filter, scriptInsertRegex, replacementString);
```

The regex response filter is based on a blog post [here](http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/minify-html-with-net-mvc-actionfilter/). Note I am not trying to remove whitespace I'm trying to insert a scrip tag but that is irrelevant.

The write method of the RegexResponseFilter is as so. The rest is the same as the blogpost.

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    // capture the data and convert to string
    var data = new byte[count];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);

    // filter the string
    var s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    s = regex.Replace(s, replacement);

    // write the data to stream 
    var outdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
    response.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
}
```

This works great in isolation. But when I applied a compression attribute (fairly standard one seen in any number of places on the internets), the thing broke with FF4 giving the error message.

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

I smelled a red herring and removed the InsertScript attribute and it works. So the two are conflicting in some way. Here is the compression attribute for completeness.

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //get request and response
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        //get encoding
        var encoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encoding))
            return;

        encoding = encoding.ToUpperInvariant();


        if (encoding.Contains("DEFLATE") || encoding == "*")
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (encoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

It's probably something obvious but this looks like it should work. The insert should get applied before the compression takes place.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flipping the order of inclusion:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Put)]
[Compress(Order = 1)]
[InsertScript(Order = 2)]
public ViewResult Service(Page page) { //omitted }
```

Another possibility is to combine multiple filters like this and then use a single action filter attribute:

```
response.Filter = new CompressStream(new InsertScript(response.Filter));
```

For this to work you need to write a custom `CompressStream` class the same way you did with the `InsertScript` and then have a single action filter attribute which will combine the two streams.